# Optimistic Locking / CAS with Amazon DynamoDB in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, locking, amazon-dynamodb

I was wondering how to use non-blocking optimistic locking (a.k.a. "Optimistic concurrency control", "Check and Set", or "Test and Set") with DynamoDB in PHP. I see examples for this in Java and .NET in the online documentation, but not for PHP.

The functionality I'm looking for is analogous to [Memcached::cas()](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.cas.php) in PHP. Is this available, and if so, where is the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same updateItem method with the `Expected` attribute:

```
$response = $client->updateItem(array(
    "TableName" => $tableName,
    "Key" => array(
        "Id" => array(Type::NUMBER => 121)
    ),
    "AttributeUpdates" => array(
        "Price" => array(
            "Value" => array(Type::NUMBER => 25)
        )
    ),
    "Expected" => array(
        "Price" => array(
            "Value" => array(Type::NUMBER => 20)
        )
    ),
    "ReturnValues" => ReturnValue::ALL_NEW
));
```

See some more examples here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelPHPItemOperationsExample.html

Comment: So we can implement the token manually - and increment it each update. Good enough, this works.

Comment: getItem is supposed to return a cas_token in case datastructure is complex and a separate attribute ourside the user data has to be used as token. Any idea how to implement that ?